# Is there a way to where when my laptop lid is opened, to automatically press a key?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, vlc

I recently started using VLC as my background engine, however, when I shut the lid, the video stops. Pressing the play/pause key on the keyboard fixes it. Is there a way to where it will automatically press the play button every time the lid is opened?

If not, is there a way to stop VLC from pausing when the lid is shut? It would help greatly. The method of stopping VLC from pausing would be more... "legit" I would say.

Comment: Background engine?

Answer (score 1):

There may be ways to stop your Mac from sleeping when you close the lid, but none of them are recommended, and I'm not even sure the old ways work anymore.

### Option 1: sleepwatcher

As far as automating VLC on system wake, that may be possible with [sleepwatcher](https://www.bernhard-baehr.de). You ought to able to simulate a press of the spacebar with a bit of AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
  key code 49 -- space bar
end tell
```

but you may need to add a slight pause (I'd start with 3 seconds and then adjust down until it failed) so that the system if fully awake before you send it.

That will also fail if VLC is not the front-most app. (Do you have to enter a password when you open the lid? If so, that's another consideration.)

---

### Option 2: [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)

I would be much more likely to use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) for this. For one thing, it does a lot more than just this one thing, and it can run that AppleScript I mentioned above.

It could also make sure that VLC is the active application and then press the `Playback » Play` menu item, which is probably more likely to work more reliably than `sleepwatcher` can.

The only downside is that Keyboard Maestro isn't free, but IMO it's one of the best purchases you can make for your Mac.